# how to show like chat box for the div/p tag top left/right corners

Tags: html, css

we are developing **chat application** in that application we are showing text in div but i want to give css like **chat box direction** for that **div(top right/left border)**  like below screen shot.

i marked in red color in the screen shot what exactly i need to do

**requirement screen shot**
[image]

```css
.right {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: right;
  right: 20px;
}

.right::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: -1px;
  right: -10px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #ccc;
}

.right::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 0px;
  right: -8px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid white;
  clear: both;
  
}

div{
  clear: right;
}

.right img {
 display: block;
 height: auto;
 max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
  <span>thanks</span>
</div>

<div class="right">
  <p style="margin-top: 0px;margin-bottom: 0px;color:green;font-size: 11px;">Kranti</p>
  <span>thanks</span>
   <p style="float: left;margin-bottom: 0px;color:red;font-size: 11px;">2:33 PM</p>
</div>



<div class="right">
  <span>thanks</span>
</div>
```

how to give Give name ,time and message in the chat box.
like below screen shot i want

[image]

Comment: kindly refer http://codepen.io/chriscoyier/pen/FCIap

Comment: also this https://jsfiddle.net/cjkmevpy/

Comment: how to do secodnd screen shot in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use pseudoelements ::after and ::before.

```css
.right {
  position: relative;
  background: aqua;
  text-align: right;
  min-width: 45%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: right;
  right: 20px;
}

.right::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: -1px;
  right: -10px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #ccc;
}

.right::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 0px;
  right: -8px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid aqua;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
  <span>thanks</span>
</div>
```

For example https://jsfiddle.net/2bekec10/

Comment: i want show name and time in chat message how to do that

Comment: how to do second screen shot

Comment: it's easy - https://jsfiddle.net/2bekec10/1/  If answer is accepted, please note this

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/69ya1b1x/2/ : i don't want take the max-width and if name is bigger than meassage looking not good and if message is single text also not good

Comment: and when ever hold on message box i want to hide/remove that but jquerymobile tabhold is not working https://jsfiddle.net/69ya1b1x/3/