# change background div color indicator direction from right to left

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change this 'upper top right' indicator to the 'upper top left' indicator.
[image: right top indicating]

```css
.right {
  position: relative;
  background: aqua;
  text-align: right;
  min-width: 45%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: right;
  right: 20px;
}

.right::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: -1px;
  right: -10px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #ccc;
}

.right::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 0px;
  right: -8px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid aqua;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
  <span>thanks</span>
</div>
```

I've tried to change 'right' to 'left' in css. But no luck yet.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/36715933/6677650

https://jsfiddle.net/2bekec10/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change right to left in before and after selectors.

```css
.right {
  position: relative;
  background: aqua;
  text-align: right;
  min-width: 45%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: right;
  right: 20px;
}

.right::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: -1px;
  left: -10px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #ccc;
}

.right::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 0px;
  left: -8px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid aqua;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="right">
  <span>thanks</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple, just replace all instances of `right` with `left`?

```css
.left {
  position: relative;
  background: aqua;
  text-align: left;
  min-width: 45%;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  left: 20px;
}

.left::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: -1px;
  left: -10px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid #ccc;
}

.left::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  visibility: visible;
  top: 0px;
  left: -8px;
  border: 10px solid transparent;
  border-top: 10px solid aqua;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">
  <span>thanks</span>
</div>
```